# How do I add embedded YouTube videos in a field?

Tags: 7, files

I would like to have a field for adding YouTube videos; however, I do not want to use the Media module because it is very buggy at this point. Is there any alternative for Drupal 7?

Comment: Saying its "very buggy at this point" makes this question too localized. The Media module is where all effort for D7 media is being made, and most people using the most recent dev version have had great success.

Comment: I just experimented with it for about two hours encountering several bugs including not being about to change the preset image dimensions. I'm just going to let the pros work on it a little more before I start to bother with it.

Comment: I don't see the question as too localized; I see it as a question about embedding videos without to use the Media module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 6, you would use [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) (emfield) to do this, but that module is being replaced with Media module in D7. Some people [are arguing](http://drupal.org/node/957544) that emfield should be ported to D7 for the time being, until Media reaches a stable version.

An interesting workaround is that of the [Vimeo Link Formatter](http://drupal.org/node/957544) module, which is a formatter for the link field provided by [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module. If you can write php, it might not be too hard to alter that module and make a youtube-equivalent for yourself (and maybe the rest of the community).

Comment: I think that I will be able to create a youtube version of this.

Comment: Great. If you can, please share it with the community, either as a separate contrib module or as part of the Vimeo Link Formatter module.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the [Video Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_filter) module, here is a quote from its project page:

> This is a highly flexible and easily extendable filter module to embed any type of video in your site using a simple token. Other modules can add video sites/formats (called codecs) using an easy plugin architecture.
>
> With WYSIWYG installed, you can use the Video Filter button to easily add videos in a rich text editor.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on D7 was the [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field). The media field was too complex, and emfield D7 port didn't work at all. The video filter mentioned above seems great but it doesn't provide a field, so it was not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues with the media - youtube module as well (D7). I think you could just create 2 fields: one for the youtube embed code and one for the youtube image thumbnail. Then show the thumbnail in the teaser display and the embed code in the full display.