# How do I display a link as an embedded player?

Tags: 7, media

I want to create a field as a link.  I want this link to be displayed as a custom embedded player.

I have checked out [How do I add embedded YouTube videos in a field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/how-do-i-add-embedded-youtube-videos-in-a-field) and the [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield) module however this solution does not work for me.

1. I do not like the admin interface/configuration.
2. The module does not support my flash player.

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Drupal Tutorial - Creating an embedded video or audio player for a link field](http://www.strykerenterprise.com/blog/drupal-tutorial-creating-embedded-video-or-audio-player-link-field)

Dependency Modules:

- [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link)
- [Custom formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to create you own module.   Checkout [Media Link](http://drupal.org/sandbox/istryker/1700312)

Below is the code you would need. This module adds a [podbean](http://www.podbean.com) audio player display for your link field.  *Modify the theme code for your embedded player.*  Another good place to look at is the [field example module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example!field_example.module/7).

Again, this module requires the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Defines a display format for a link that will embed a player.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function media_link_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'audio_player' => array(
      'label' => t('Audio Player'),
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      'field types' => array('link_field'),
    ),
    /*
    'video_player' => array(
      'label' => t('Video Player'),
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      'field types' => array('link_field'),
    ),
    */
  );
}


/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function media_link_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $elements = array();
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    $elements[$delta] = array(
      '#markup' => theme('link_formatter_'. $display['type'], array('element' => $item, 'field' => $instance)),
    );
  }
  return $elements;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function media_link_theme() {
  return array(
      'link_formatter_audio_player' => array(
          'variables' => array('element' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Theme function for 'audio player' link field formatter.
 */
function theme_link_formatter_audio_player($vars) {

  $url = $vars['element']['url'];
  return "<div>" .
  "<object classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0' width='210' height='25' id='mp3playerlightsmallv3' align='middle'>" .
  "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />" .
  "<param name='movie' value='http://www.podbean.com/podcast-audio-video-blog-player/mp3playerlightsmallv3.swf?audioPath=" . $url . "&autoStart=no' />" .
  "<param name='quality' value='high' /><param name='bgcolor' value='#ffffff' /><param name='wmode' value='transparent' />" .
  "<embed src='http://www.podbean.com/podcast-audio-video-blog-player/mp3playerlightsmallv3.swf?audioPath=" . $url . "&autoStart=no' quality='high'  width='210' height='25' name='mp3playerlightsmallv3' align='middle' allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' wmode='transparent' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' /></embed>" .
  "</object>" .
  "</div>";
}

?>
```